# User logged-in Persistence with jwt Tokens and React after Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, local-storage

I am working with React and Jwt Tokens and so far a user can stay logged in after going to a login page. I have a problem when I reload the page that the user won't stay logged in. Currently when a user logs in, I store the jwt Token in localStorage. For some reason, I don't understand why I'm not returning a valid user even when I have the jwt Token in localStorage. Any help is appreciated!

```html
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from 'react'
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const initialState = {
    user: null
}

if(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')) {
    const decodedToken = jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'))

    if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken')
    }
    else {
        initialState.user = null;
    }
}


const AuthContext = createContext({
    user:null,
    login: (userData) => {},
    logout: () => {}
})

function authReducer(state, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return {
                ...state,
                user:null
            }
        default: return state
    }
}

function AuthProvider(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState)

    function login(userData) {
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", userData.token)
        dispatch({
            type:'LOGIN',
            payload:userData
        })

    }

    function logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken")
        dispatch({type:'LOGOUT'})
    }

    return (<AuthContext.Provider
        value={{ user: state.user, login, logout}}
        {...props} /> )
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider }
```

^^^ My Authentication file

[image: My context called to grab a user.]

^^ My menu bar component renders dynamically based on if there is a user or not. It's not rendering a logged-in user after reloading so my authentication file must be doing something wrong.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Quick additional info: I confirmed in my browser that localStorage is storing the correct jwtToken after a reload.

Comment: Where do you ever use the token you loaded? All I can see is that if it is expired, you delete it from storage and if not, you delete the `initialState.user`.

Comment: yea, I was following this tutorial and that's how he wrote it and for some reason his users stay persistent after a reload. I was following this tutorial if it helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewLrGMt7MQY&list=PLMhAeHCz8S3_pgb-j51QnCEhXNj5oyl8n&index=5